# Android Client/Server Socket communication using Service or IntentService

Tags: android, sockets, android-service

So far I was able to start a Server on one android device (wifi tethering/hotspot) and let the Client (another android) connect and send messages to the server. The server then replyed to that. I realize I need a way to keep the server listening to Clients, even if the chat app isn't running. Clients should be able to send message and the server should receive this. **Should I use Service or IntentService to archieve this?** I can't extend from AsyncTask & Service...how to implement this? Some example code would be great.

This is how my Server looks like:

```
public class Server extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Socket> {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private TextView textView;
    private String incomingMsg;
    private String outgoingMsg;

    public Server(TextView textView) {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    public void closeServer() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Server", "Closung the server caused a problem");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }


    @Override
    protected Socket doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(params[0]);       

            //accept connections
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");

            //send a message
            outgoingMsg = "You are connected to the Server" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            out.write(outgoingMsg);
            out.flush();

            return socket;


        } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
            //if timeout occurs
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
//      finally {
//          if (serverSocket != null) {
//              try {
//                  serverSocket.close();
//              } catch (IOException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
//          }
//      }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Socket socket) {

        if(socket != null) {
            try {

                Log.i("Server", "Server received: " + incomingMsg);
                textView.setText("Server received: " + incomingMsg + "\n");

                textView.append("Server sent: " + outgoingMsg + "\n");
                Log.i("Server", "Server sent: " + outgoingMsg);

                socket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("Server", "Can't communicate with the client!");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Client:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Socket> {

    private WifiManager wifi;
    private Context context;
    private String outMsg;
    private String inMsg;

    public Client(Context context, WifiManager wifiManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.wifi = wifiManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected Socket doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {

            String gateway = intToIp(wifi.getDhcpInfo().gateway);
            Socket socket = new Socket(gateway, params[0]);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            String ipAdress = intToIp(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

            outMsg = ", Client " + ipAdress +" is connecting!" + System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
            out.write(outMsg);
            out.flush();

            //accept server response
            inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");

            return socket;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null; 
    }


    public String intToIp(int addr) {
        return  ((addr & 0xFF) + "." + 
                ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." + 
                ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." + 
                ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF));
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Socket socket) {

        if(socket != null) {

            Log.i("Client", "Client sent: " + outMsg);
            Toast.makeText(context, "\nClient sent: " + outMsg + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.i("Client", "Client received: " + inMsg);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Client received: " + inMsg + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Log.d("Client", "Can't connect to server!");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't connect to server!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
    }
}
```

**How to make a Service out of the Server? Should the Client be a Service as well?**

Comment: No just keep the Server in service

Comment: ok, what about using Service or IntentService? How to combine this with AsyncTask in case of a Service?

Answer (score 3):

Use a service but forget about the AsyncTask. Have your service start up your generic Threads (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and setup your sockets + listeners. This service can even handle the sending of messages too (via one of the many options that covered in the below link).

Don't forget to properly cleanup the Threads in onDestroy() of the Service.

Also note that if you want the app to continue to receive messages from other clients, you'll need to make sure the service is forced into the foreground (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification). However, this isn't foolproof, your service can still be killed.

This is why people tend to use servers hosted on some dedicated box as opposed to each individual device...

Comment: Would using an ExecutorService with a newFixedThreadPool (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool) be prudent here?

Comment: Certainly, if you're running multiple threads, it's a good idea to manage them with an ExecutorService. A newFixedThreadPool might mean you're limiting the number of users that can connect, depending on how you architect the server (what protocol, etc?).